# Script for Python Hanoi Tower OOP

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, tower-of-hanoi

Is my Python Script to play Hanoi Tower respectful of OOP spirit?

I have difficulties to create meaningful classes so I started an easy project. Here is one class at the plateau level and then a class to handle towers.

How can it be improved (on the OOP level and on script level)?

I want then a GUI with TKinter, a third class GUI would be suited ?

Thank you

```
import numpy as np
NB_DISKS = 3

class Plateau:
    """Class for the whole plateau"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.init_plateau()

    def init_plateau(self):
        """List of towers,first tower full"""
        self.nb_disks = NB_DISKS
        self.towers = [Tower(self.nb_disks), Tower(0), Tower(0)]

    def motion(self, tower_from, tower_to): 
        """Motion from one tower to another one with checking"""
        from_tower = self.towers[tower_from-1]
        to_tower = self.towers[tower_to-1]

        if from_tower.get_last_disk()>to_tower.get_last_disk():  #Receive 0 if to_tower is empty
            disk = from_tower.get_last_disk()
            from_tower.delete_disk()
            to_tower.add_disk(disk) 

            self.check_victory()
            self.print_towers()
        else:
            print('Last disk number from origin has to be bigger than reception one')

    def check_victory(self):
        """Check if last tower has an ordered list or not"""
        last_tower = self.towers[2].get_whole_tower()
        if len(last_tower) == self.nb_disks:
            diff_last_tower = np.diff(last_tower)
            if np.unique(diff_last_tower) == 1:   
                print('victory:')                
                self.print_towers()
                print('new plateau:')
                self.init_plateau()   

    def print_towers(self):
        """Print the towers"""
        for elt in self.towers:
            elt.print_tower()
        print('\n')

class Tower:
    """Class for a tower"""
    def __init__(self,nb_disks):
        """Creation of a tower"""
        if nb_disks !=0:
            self.tower = list(range(1, nb_disks+1))
        else:
            self.tower = []

    def get_last_disk(self):
        """Return last element of the tower"""
        if self.tower == []:
            return 0
        else:
            return self.tower[-1]

    def delete_disk(self):
        """Delete last disk of the tower"""
        self.tower.pop()

    def add_disk(self,disk):
        """Add a disk to the top of the tower"""
        self.tower.append(disk)

    def get_whole_tower(self):
        """Return the complete tower"""
        return(self.tower)

    def print_tower(self): 
        """Print the element of the tower"""
        print(self.tower)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Plateau()
    game.motion(1,3)
    game.motion(1,3)   # Try to move a big disk on a small one 
    game.motion(1,2)
    game.motion(3,2)   
    game.motion(1,3)
    game.motion(2,1)    
    game.motion(2,3)  
    game.motion(1,3)
```

Answer (score 4):

From the OOP/typing level, you might want to consider having `Disk` be a type.  If it doesn't need any methods, you could just make it a subtype of `int`:

```
from typing import NewType

Disk = NewType('Disk', int)
```

Some notes on your interfaces:

1. Since you always use `get_last_disk` and `delete_disk` together, why not combine them?  The thing you really want is a `pop_top_disk` operation that removes and returns the last disk (that's already how you're implementing `delete_disk` anyway).
2. `add_disk` could implement the "no larger disk on a smaller one" rule.
3. `get_whole_tower` seems bad because it's exposing the internal data structure of the tower; this violates your entire OOP abstraction.  Note also that in general you should distinguish between "private" and "public" members of your classes.
4. Rather than making `NB_DISKS` a global and having `Plateau` initialize itself from that, `Plateau`'s initializer should take the number of disks as a parameter.
5. The Pythonic way of making a "print" function is to implement the magic function `__repr__` to return a string.
6. The int values of your disks should be reversed so that bigger numbers represent bigger disks.
7. This is more an English thing than a Python thing, but the verb form of "motion" is "move" so it would be better to name your method `move`.  :)

Here's the final code I came up with after implementing the above suggestions:

```
from typing import NewType

Disk = NewType('Disk', int)

class WrongOrder(Exception):
    def __init__(self, top: int, bottom: int) -> None:
        super().__init__("Can't put a disk of size %d on a disk of size %d" % (top, bottom))

class Plateau:
    """Class for the whole plateau"""
    def __init__(self, nb_disks: int) -> None:
        self._init_plateau(nb_disks)

    def _init_plateau(self, nb_disks: int) -> None:
        self._towers = [Tower(nb_disks), Tower(0), Tower(0)]

    def move(self, from_tower: int, to_tower: int) -> None: 
        """Move from one tower to another (towers specified as an int from 1-3).  
        Prints an error if the move is invalid."""
        # Convert from 1-index to 0-index.
        from_tower -= 1
        to_tower -= 1
        # Make the move, print exception if it fails.
        try:
            disk = self._towers[from_tower].pop_top_disk()
            try:
                self._towers[to_tower].add_disk(disk)
            except WrongOrder:
                # don't drop the disk!  Put it back where we got it and reraise.
                self._towers[from_tower].add_disk(disk)
                raise
        except Exception as e:
            print('Move failed: ', str(e))
        else:
            self._check_victory()
            print(self)


    def _check_victory(self) -> None:
        """Check if all disks have moved to the last tower (victory condition).
        If the player has achieved victory, reset the game.
        """
        if sum(tower.height for tower in self._towers) == self._towers[2].height:
            print('victory:')                
            print(self)
            print('new plateau:')
            self._init_plateau(self._towers[2].height)   

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        """Print the towers"""
        return "\n".join([repr(tower) for tower in self._towers]) + "\n"

class Tower:
    """Class for a tower"""
    def __init__(self, nb_disks: int) -> None:
        """Creation of a tower"""
        self._tower = [Disk(size) for size in range(1, nb_disks + 1)]
        self._tower.reverse()  # order the stack from largest to smallest

    def pop_top_disk(self) -> Disk:
        """Remove and return the top disk on this tower."""
        return self._tower.pop()

    def add_disk(self, disk: Disk) -> None:
        """Add a disk to the top of the tower.
        Raises WrongOrder if the disk being added is too big.
        """
        if len(self._tower) and self._tower[-1] < disk:
            raise WrongOrder(disk, self._tower[-1])
        self._tower.append(disk)

    @property
    def height(self) -> int:
        """Number of disks in the tower."""
        return len(self._tower)

    def __repr__(self) -> str: 
        """Print the elements of the tower"""
        return repr(self._tower)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Plateau(3)
    game.move(1,3)
    game.move(1,3)   # Try to move a big disk on a small one 
    game.move(1,2)
    game.move(3,2)   
    game.move(1,3)
    game.move(2,1)    
    game.move(2,3)  
    game.move(1,3)
```

Comment: This is mostly good. I may add an answer of my own, but I wanted to react to your point #1: In OP's code, they _did not_ always use `get_last_disk` and `delete_disk` together, because they weren't treating illegal moves as exceptional. Between your nested-`try` pattern and what OP wrote, I think I'd prefer the original!

Comment: Thanks, you provided me nice advices on POO and Python. I will look more for @Property, __repr__ and exception handling. NewType seems also to be a nice feature

Answer (score 4):

The "spirit" of Object Oriented Programming is two-fold:

- To give us an enforceable metaphor for reasoning about our code. ("objects" as objects)
- To give us heuristics about how to compartmentalize out code. (encapsulation)

The purist perspective of OOP can be a bit verbose, and in python it's not usually necessary.

> I want then a GUI with TKinter, a third class GUI would be suited ?

Try thinking about it like this: An object method will have *both* a method that it's called on *and a context in which it gets called.* If you build a class to encapsulate your GUI, where will it's methods get called from?

One of the principal things objects do is manage state. If a function needs to *update* state, that suggests that the function and the state could be encapsulated together in an object. If the function just needs to *read* a state, and that state (data) could be passed in as an argument by the calling context, then the function can be a static method or a global function. If a class *only* has static methods, then you don't need a class at all. That's a good thing: the less state you're managing the less opportunity to mess it up.

> How can it be improved (on the OOP level and on script level)?

[Sam Stafford's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/234606/200133) points #4 and #5 are good, as is the suggestion to have `Disk` as a new type.

1. You could also neglect to declare a proper class for the Towers by just having `Tower = NewType('Tower', List(Disk))`.
2. If you're thinking of the normal input and output as a user-interface, then you probably shouldn't be printing (or reading input) from inside class methods. That said, *logging* is a fine thing to do, and `print` is a low-effort way to do it.
3. `Plateau.motion()` does too many things. Checking for victory should certainly go outside in the calling context. I would suggest that validating the user-input also doesn't belong in there.
4. Similarly, `Plateau.check_victory()` shouldn't set up the new game, and `init_plateau` should get inlined into `Plateau.__init__()`. When you start a new game just build a new Plateau.

Taken to the extreme, you could have a static class representing the state of the game, and a function to start a new game, and then you'd repeatedly call a function `(GameState, PlayerMove)->GameState`. At that point you'd be breaking past traditional imperative OOP into a more "functional" style.